# Count the number of subsequent groups in an array

Tags: arrays, delphi

The question may seem a little obscure, but I'll try to break it down in layman's terms.

Let's say I have an array of 24 `Byte` values, containing only `0` or `1`:

```
011000100000001000000111
```

The array is logically divided into groups of four values per group, which gives us:

```
0110 0010 0000 0010 0000 0111
```

Now, I'd like to count, how many subsequent groups have **at least** one value set to `1`. In the example I provided, we have `2` subsequent groups.

How should I go about that programatically?

Comment: sorry, I must resist this one, it's more like a question of logic than anything...

Comment: It is a bit 'provocative' that you say you'll try to explain in 'layman's terms', especially since your previous description of the problem is incorrect (at least not unambiguous).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - it may be a language issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on Arnaud's answer, which has the right idea but doesn't actually do what the OP asked for:

```
function CountNonNullGroupSequenceLength(Values: PByte; ValuesCount: integer): integer;
var Groups: PIntegerArray;
    i, counter: integer;
begin
  Groups := Values;
  result := 0;
  counter := 0;
  for i := 0 to (ValuesCount shr 2)-1 do
    if Groups[i]<>NULLGROUP then
      inc(counter)
    else begin
      result := max(result, counter);
      counter := 0;
    end;
  result := max(result, counter);
end;
```

Make sure to put `Math` in your **uses** list so you can get the `Max` function.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I had to modify it slightly, because it didn't want to compile under Delphi XE2, but nevertheless, it's a good piece of code.

Comment: I came up with my own solution, but after seeing yours, I made sure that my code is not to be recovered from the hdd, anymore. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since a group is 4 bytes, this is just like a typecast of the 4 bytes into one integer.

For instance:

```
const
  NULLGROUP = 0;

function CountNonNullGroups(const Values: TByteArray): integer;
var Groups: TIntegerArray absolute Values;
    i: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 0 to (length(Values) shr 2)-1 do
    if Groups[i]<>NULLGROUP then
      inc(result);
end;
```

Or with pointers:

```
function CountNonNullGroups(Values: PByte; ValuesCount: integer): integer;
var Groups: PIntegerArray;
    i: integer;
begin
  Groups := Values;
  result := 0;
  for i := 0 to (ValuesCount shr 2)-1 do
    if Groups[i]<>NULLGROUP then
      inc(result);
end;
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the problem. But that is easily done, due to a non-ideal description made by the OP. You are simply counting the number of non-zero groups. The OP wants to find the maximum length of a 'chain' of subsequent non-zero groups.

Comment: Yes, I did not implement the "subsequent" pattern. My mistake. ;)